# Int object is not callable in Investment (interest) Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print an answer to my compounding interest formula, but it keeps saying that my integer isn't callable.

```
#Ask user what P equals
P = int(input('What is the initial investment? '))
#Ask user for the meaning of r
r = int(input('What is the annual nominal interest rate? '))
#Ask user for meaning of n
n = int(input('How many times will your interest compound this year? '))
#Ask user for t 
t = int(input('How many years are you planning to invest? '))
#Compute compounding interest formula 
A = P(1+(r/n))**nt
#convert line 30 into a String 
A = str(A)
#Print statement
print('You will have $',A, "in", t, 'years.')
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
A = P(1+(r/n))**nt
```

I assume you meant to do multiplication?

```
A = P*(1+(r/n))**(n*t)
```

Also note you need `//` to do "true division" instead of integer division

```
r // n
```

Comment: Also, `nt` should be `(n*t)`.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all you forget to do multiplication, result got an error.

here is the correct way

```
A = P*(1+(r/n))**(n*t)
```

or

Instead of using `**` you can also use python's builtin function called pow

> The pow() function returns the value of x to the power of y (x^y).

```
A = P * (pow((1 + r / n),(n*t)))
```